# How can I print part of String in Java? e.g.: The string is "Application No: ABCD" and I just want to print only ABCD?

Tags: java, string

How can I print part of String in Java?
e.g.: The string is "Application No: ABCD" and I just want to print only ABCD?

Comment: substring it, replace the beginning,  probably use regex. There are multiple ways

Comment: Have you tried something yet?  More important, did you spend any time researching this before posting to Stack Overflow?

Comment: Would be faster to use a search engine than sign up to SO, post question and wait for answer. Plus you'd feel like you have learned and achieved something.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print only specific parts of a string in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23019070/how-to-print-only-specific-parts-of-a-string-in-java)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a string in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split te string from ":",

```
    String yourstr = "Application No: ABCD";
    String[] words= yourstr.split(":");
    System.out.println(words[1]);
```